# Speed up image load when using particle effect, d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to make a particle effect that follows the user's mouse around. It works perfectly if I don't include the image, but it's tremendously slow once I add in the image. I tried working out how to define the image differently, or using a def, but could not make anything else work.

JSFiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/jqkuf5os/

The image is hosted in the same path as the app, and is 1.2kb

```
<svg id="mySvg" width="40" height="40">
    <defs id="mdef">
        <pattern id="image" x="0" y="0" height="40" width="40">    
            <image x="0" y="0" width="40" height="40" xlink:href="image.png"></image>    
        </pattern>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

And the js

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

svg.append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .on("ontouchstart" in document ? "touchmove" : "mousemove", particle);


function particle() {

    var m = d3.mouse(this);

    svg.append("circle")
        .attr("cx", m[0])
        .attr("cy", m[1])
        .attr("r", 1e-6)
        .style("stroke", d3.hsl((i = (i + 1) % 360), 1, .5))
        .style("stroke-opacity", 1)
        .style("fill", "url(#image)")
        .transition()
        .duration(2000)
        .ease(Math.sqrt)
        .attr("r", 40)
        .style("stroke-opacity", 1e-6)
        .remove();

    d3.event.preventDefault();
}
```

How do I handle the image loading so it's faster?

Comment: It's not the image loading, it's the determination of the fill of the circle.  If you just use an image, it behaves much nicer:  http://jsfiddle.net/jqkuf5os/1/